# Scroll when key pressed?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, mouse

I'm on a Windows machine with an ALPS trackpad looking for a way to get mac-like scrolling for web browsing, etc. So far the best option I've found is the "ChromeTouch" extension for Google Chrome.

Is there an extension or driver that will allow continuous scrolling with a single finger as long as a certain key (say, the Windows key) is held down? I believe this would be a significant improvement on what I've found so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm now using the [ChromeTouch extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ncegfehgjifmmpnjaihnjpbpddjjebme) (for web browsing) and [MouseImpPro Live!](http://www.mouseimp.com/) (for the rest of Windows). Much better than using the scroll bar!

[image]

[image]

Comment: * Both of the above are freeware.